# could you please let me know what is wrong with this code?

Tags: winforms, powershell

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)

$ColName = @{Expression={$_.CSNAME};Label="SERVER NAME"},
           @{Expression={$_.Caption};Label="OS NAME"; width =25},
           @{Expression={$_.OSArchitecture};Label="OS TYPE"}
$out = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "suman-pc" |
       Format-Table -HideTableHeaders $ColName

list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$list.Insert($out)

$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView -Property @{
  Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
  ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
  DataSource = $list
}

$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```

The above code is generating the below error. my objective is collect OS name for multiple system, and present it in datagrid format

```
New-List : Cannot bind parameter 'MarkerOffset'. Cannot convert value
"System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "System.Double". Error: "Input string
was not in a correct format."
At C:\Users\Suman\AppData\Local\Temp\4abe9ca5-3580-4c58-918b-9f1f721c1f32.ps1:10 char:19
+ list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-List], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,AutoGenerateCmdlets669798327.NewListCommand

Cannot find an overload for "Insert" and the argument count: "1".
At :\Users\Suman\AppData\Local\Temp\4abe9ca5-3580-4c58-918b-9f1f721c1f32.ps1:11 char:1
+ $list.Insert($out)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but have you considered `Out-GridView`?

Comment: You miss `$` before variable name.

Comment: list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList should be $list = ... Also, insert requires to specify an index.

Comment: The code in your question produces a number of errors, but not the first one you posted. Please post your actual code, not something you fabricated or typed from memory. The second error you get, because `Insert()` expects 2 arguments, as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use `Add()` if you just want to append an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a couple of reasons here.

First **you dont want to use Format-Table** since it goes only as representive output.

Second you using wrong method, you should using **$list.Add()** instead of **$list.Insert()**

Here's fixed code:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)

$ColName = @{Expression={$_.CSNAME};Label="SERVER NAME"},
           @{Expression={$_.Caption};Label="OS NAME";},
           @{Expression={$_.OSArchitecture};Label="OS TYPE"}
$out = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "suman-pc" | Select-Object $ColName

$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
[void]$list.Add($out)

$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView -Property @{
  Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)
  ColumnHeadersVisible = $true
  DataSource = $list
}

$form.Controls.Add($dataGridView)
$form.ShowDialog()
```